# Mega Menu CSS Need Fixed

Tags: css, megamenu

i learn to create my own wp themes. but i have problem when create megamenu. i would say thanks, for someone help me.  how to full width, this megamenu.

```
<nav id="navigation">
<ul class="pagemenu">
    <li class="megamenu">
        <a title="<?php echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?>" href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>">Megamenu</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h3><a title="<?php echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?>" href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>">Celebrity</a></h3>
                <p><a title="<?php echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?>" href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>">Celebrity</a></p>
                <p><a title="<?php echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?>" href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>">Technology</a></p>
                <p><a title="<?php echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?>" href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>">Business</a></p>
                <p><a title="<?php echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?>" href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>">Fashion</a></p>
                <p><a title="<?php echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?>" href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>">Celebrity</a></p>
                <p><a title="<?php echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?>" href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>">Technology</a></p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Here's are the link [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarkem/0n4zns83/)

have a good day

devan

Answer (score 0):

you can just give these setting to fill whole width

```
#navigation li.megamenu{
 width: 100%;
}
#navigation li.megamenu ul{
 width: 100%
}
```

is this you want??
[jsfiles](https://jsfiddle.net/0n4zns83/2/)

Comment: thanks for your reply, but if i set witdh 100% on li.megamenu it will appear too to other menu list, [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarkem/0n4zns83/3/)